# Is there a way to return 3 files together with some data calculations from one Django request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jsonresponse

I have a Django request doing some ML calculations. The request takes 3 files as input and generates several files as an output together with some temperature data calculations that I need, therefore I need to return content type = "multipart/form-data" as a Django Response.

If I try using **rest_framework.response** then I get: `TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple`

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response(thermal_response["data"], status=thermal_response["statusCode"])
```

If I try using **JSONResponse** I get:
`TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
JsonResponse(thermal_response["data"], safe=False)
```

Comment: Did you already consider zipping those 3 files together and then send the .zip file via [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse)

Comment: But how can I attach my temperature calculations data next to the zip in a FileResponse?

Comment: Ok, that I don't know. Maybe just add a 4th short textfile that contains the data and then ship it all together as mentioned .zip file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implicity convert ndarray into Json. try `tolist` method, which allows you to convert an array to a list:

```
JsonResponse(thermal_response["data"].tolist(), safe=False)
```